# Filter circular (directions) data overlapping zero

Tags: r

I have a data set including flight directions of birds and to refine one of the analyses, I wanted to filter the data so that I only investigate directions from west (270) to north (0) to east (90).

Filtering the data to include only eastern to western directions works, however, somehow, applying a filter that overlaps zero does not work.

The below example should illustrate the context.

```
library(circular)
library(viridis)

df <- data.frame(flight_dir = runif(n = 1000, min = 0, max = 359),
                 hourOfNight = sample(1:8, 1000, replace = TRUE),
                 n_birds = sample(100:3000, 1000, replace = TRUE),
                 mean_headwind = sample(-10, 10, 1000, replace = TRUE))

df <- df %>% mutate(flight_dir = as.circular(flight_dir,
                                             type = "directions",
                                             units = "degrees",
                                             template = "geographics",
                                             modulo = "2pi",
                                             zero = pi/2,
                                             rotation = "clock"))

df %>% filter(between(flight_dir,
                      circular(270, type = "directions", units = "degrees", template = "geographics", modulo = "2pi", zero = pi/2, rotation = "clock"),
                      circular(90, type = "directions", units = "degrees", template = "geographics", modulo = "2pi", zero = pi/2, rotation = "clock")),
              n_birds >= 1000) %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x = hourOfNight,
             y = mean_headwind)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,
             linetype = "dashed",
             size = .5) +
  geom_smooth(aes(weight = n_birds),
              method = "loess") +
  geom_point(aes(size = n_birds,
                 fill = n_birds),
             shape = 21,
             alpha = .5) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "MTR",
                       option = "turbo",
                       guide = "legend") +
  scale_size(name = "MTR",
             guide = "legend") +
  theme_bw()
```

The plot that is then drawn is just empty, although there should be plenty of observations with a flight direction somewhere in between 270 and 90 degrees.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Explicitly list all non-base R packages you are using.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question and provided a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were tiny corrections that were needed.

1. You probably want to change what I commented.

```
df <- data.frame(flight_dir = runif(n = 1000, min = 0, max = 359),
                 hourOfNight = sample(1:8, 1000, replace = TRUE),
                 n_birds = sample(100:3000, 1000, replace = TRUE),
                 #mean_headwind = sample(-10, 10, 1000, replace = TRUE))
                 mean_headwind = sample(-10:10, 1000, replace = TRUE))
```

2. And then, to filter in the condition, put the lower boundary before the higher one.

```
df %>% filter(!between(flight_dir,
                      circular(91, type = "directions", units = "degrees",
                               template = "geographics", modulo = "2pi",
                               zero = pi/2, rotation = "clock"),
                      circular(269, type = "directions", units = "degrees",
                               template = "geographics", modulo = "2pi",
                               zero = pi/2, rotation = "clock")),
              n_birds >= 1000)
```

That's it. It produced the graph for me.

**Update**: I made a change to cover your case: negating the interval between 91 and 269 degrees, covers everything else, i.e. from 270 to 90.

Comment: Thank you, but just to be sure, it is not possible to do the direction filtering from 270 to 90 directly, although it is a circular variable and it should be clear that 360 = 0?

Comment: The main issue is to get the `dplyr` filter to understand your condition. The filter does not "understand circular", if you get what I mean. To apply a direct filter you may want to use `filter(flight_dir >= 270 | flight_dir <= 90)`.